# What is the syntax for HEREDOC string in Java?

Tags: java

I read somewhere that Java 15 implemented a new way to write multi line Strings. For some reason I cannot find the related documentation.

What is the syntax for multi line strings?

I remember an official page describing all the new java features for every version, including the new string format. Where can I find that page?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to [Text Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html)?

Comment: [This](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/15/) page has links to descriptions of the new features in Java 15.